Cloud Armour policy
Team,
Looking to lock down external load balancer from CDN CIDR EdgeLocation IPs.
I was able to create the policy in Cloud Armour to allow only the CIDR ranges from CDN and was able to see the the rules starting with rule number 1000 created under the policy.
Need to know is there a way in cloud armor policy that will continue to allow all the traffic, but alert when access from non CDN ip address is seen, so I can then investigate the source of access and determine if the access should be blocked or allowed.
Trying to see in cloud armour is there any option when in I can allow all traffic, but it should alert me fron NON CDN IP CIDR range (note: I already have an edge location IP ranges)
so I can then investigate the source of access and determine if the access should be blocked or allowed.(e.g. access from monitoring systems))

fyi this is off-topic here, as it's not specific to programming. Maybe better on [sf] but... I suggest reading the guidelines there first. As written, this might be off-topic there too (you provided a requirement, but no specifics about what you tried, issues, etc - a [mcve])

I did added ELB and attached policy to it which has certain set of rule and is working fine. only question is should I allow All IP addresses which is currently set as default - deny rule.

Details belong in your question, not as a comment. But as I already mentioned, this question doesn't belong here. Please move it to the correct site.

Thanks @DavidMakogon, moved to correct site.

Was able to achieve solution by setting up the Alerting
https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/request-logging
After enabling request-logging you can use log-based-alerts to achieve your use-case.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Have you considered a preview rule? Make sure that the rule is ahead of your allow rule so that you are sure that it will fire. In the Load Balancer logs, it will generate a previewSecurityPolicy stanza in the jsonPayload section of the log line.
Something sort of like this:
gcloud compute security-policies rules create 500 --project=[projectName] --action=deny --security-policy=[policyName] --expression=\!inIpRange\(origin.ip,\ \'2.2.2.0/24\'\) --description=Alert\ when\ access\ to\ IPs\ is\ 
 not\ specific\ CIDR --preview

The CEL rule !inIpRange(origin.ip, '2.2.2.0/24') will check if the user IP address is NOT from the CIDR block range...that is what the ! value is doing at the front of the CEL rule. Then enable the preview rule.
Then, you can create an alert based on when this rule is tripped in preview mode. Since it is only in preview mode, Cloud Armor will just log it but not take any specific action on it. You can then go into Log Explorer and look at the httpRequest.remoteIp value that was logged against the request. Using my priority number value, you might run a query like this:

resource.type="http_load_balancer" 
jsonPayload.previewSecurityPolicy.priority="500"

This will pull the log lines for the preview policy you generated where you can see the IP addresses. If you want to get really fancy, you can filter the logs by IP address using the log field pane. If you open up the httpRequest stanza in the log > LEFT mouse click over the remoteIP address value (which is the connecting IP address to the Application Load Balancer) - a menu will appear with options > click on the Add field to Log fields pane . The Log field pane to the left will redraw and will list all the remoteIP addresses that match the query along with a count as to how many times that IP appeared in the logs for the time period.

Thank you for the response appreciated.I'm still checking how to apply preview rule, still not able to find how to apply, any details will help .ty!

If you are using a gCloud command, just add the --preview directive and it will generate or update the rule into preview. If you are using the UX for Cloud Armor, when you Edit or Add a rule, there will be a checkbox just below the Response Code option. Enable the checkbox and deploy (Add/Update) your rule. The Cloud Armor policy will deploy and you will see your rule will be grayed out because it is in a preview mode.
